# How to remove left and right margin from ListView row?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using a `DrawerLayout` with a `ListView` inside. The rows of the list are `TextView`s.

My problem is, that there is a margin on the left and right of each row, which I can't get rid off. Following a screenshot, where I set the pressed color to blue for illustration purpose.
[image: Sample ListView]

My `ListView` inside the `DrawerLaoyut`:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:background="@color/secondary_light_gray"/>
```

The row definition:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/icon_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/TextMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector_iconlist_bg"
    android:textColor="@drawable/list_selector_iconlist_text" >
</TextView>
```

What I tried already was setting margin and padding of the `ListView` itself, and on the row `TextViews`. Both with no effect. So, how can I get rid of these margins?

Comment: give ListView width match_parent

Comment: That only changes the width of the ListView. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and delete all margin if u give anywhere in app regarding this layout

Comment: I'll accept this answer. It pointed me in the right direction. There was some margin in the listselector drawable definition, which I oversaw "0" vs. "8" in some fonts is hard to distinguish ;)